# set of x and x does not work in let in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, chez-scheme

I'm trying to run this line in Scheme:
`(let ((x y) (y x)) (set! x x) (set! y y))`

where at the start of the program x is defined to be 1 and y is defined to be 2.
I want the output to be x=2 and y=1 but I get x=1 and y=2

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Are the values of the variables constrained to be integers?  There is a famous trick if so.

Comment: @tfb I wish but no :(

Comment: Then you need at least one temporary variable (or something like `set!-values`, which implicitly uses them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My end goal is to switch their values only with commands, not with temporary variables

It looks like racket supports [`set!-values`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/set_.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmore-scheme..rkt%29._set%21-values%29%29), so you can swap your variables without using any explicit temporary variables like so:

```
(define x 1)
(define y 2)
(set!-values (x y) (values y x))
;;; x is now 2 and y is 1
```

(It's even the example in the linked documentation)

Answer (score 1):

In this expression:

```
(set! x x)
```

Both `x` reference the same variable, the one introduced by the `let` binding. Any change you do to `x` inside the `let` (and here, the actual value is unchanged) is not visible outside the `let`, because outside the `let` the `x` symbol is *bound* to another variable.

If you rename your temporary variables `a` and `b` for example:

```
(let ((a y) (b x)) (set! x a) (set! y b))
```

You will observe a different behaviour.

Comment: yes, unfortunately, I cannot give new names to my current variables(x,y). My end goal is to switch their values only with commands, not with temporary variables

Comment: Somehow you need at least one temporary variable to exchange the values (introducing an intermediate lambda counts as having temp variables too (the parameters))